# Hello World Compile Error - Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to setup the android dev kit, I've installed everything and tried to setup a Hello World activity, however when I build the project I get the error:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\Matt\.IntelliJIdea13\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

All of this is auto generated from my IDE, so I'm not sure what the problem can be, has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Did you look to see if "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java" is actually there? If it _is_ there, you may have better luck moving it to a path that does not have a space in it (and reconfiguring your IDE for the change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as said in the comment the error is that your file missing, so the first step is to see if the file is even there, if not I would reinstall your jdk (as that file should not be missing).

If the file is there than it is most likely the case that the space in the directory is causing issue for some reason. To fix this you can either manually copy your jdk to a new directory (without a space) and replace your current jdk's location with the new one. You could also uninstall the current java distribution and reinstall the new one in a location without spaces.